# How to resolve git merge conflict, from command line, using a given strategy, for just one file?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Let's say I did a git merge and have a conflict in some file, say `package.json` or `pom.xml`, and perhaps some other files.

I would like to

1. automatically resolve merge conflicts for *certain files* from command line, while
2. letting myself resolve manually all the other conflicts, if any, and
3. making sure I don't lose valuable changes from any branch.

Because of 2), **I can't use `git merge -Xours`** as this would resolve *all* conflicts. I want to resolve only conflicts in one particular file.

Because of 3), **I can't use `git checkout --ours package.json`** as this might lose some changes from the input branch.

The use case is for instance: auto-merging script that will resolve trivial well-known conflicts in a predefined way, and fail if there are some other conflicts in other files.

The typical case I often have is having two branches with `version` field in `package.json` diverged like below:

```
$ git diff
diff --cc package.json
index 75c469b,f709434..0000000
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@@ -1,6 -1,6 +1,12 @@@
  {
    "name": "test",
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +  "version": "2.0.1",
++||||||| merged common ancestors
++  "version": "1.0.0",
++=======
+   "version": "1.0.2",
++>>>>>>> master
```

Is it possible to resolve the conflict for *just one* file, using given strategy? Something like:

```
git-resolve-conflict --ours package.json
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`git-merge-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) although its API is rather low-level.

In order to have an easy-to-use command, you can use the following bash script (to be imported to `.bashrc`, or you can also install it with `npm install -g git-resolve-conflict`):

```
git-resolve-conflict() {
  STRATEGY="$1"
  FILE_PATH="$2"

  if [ -z "$FILE_PATH" ] || [ -z "$STRATEGY" ]; then
    echo "Usage:   git-resolve-conflict <strategy> <file>"
    echo ""
    echo "Example: git-resolve-conflict --ours package.json"
    echo "Example: git-resolve-conflict --union package.json"
    echo "Example: git-resolve-conflict --theirs package.json"
    return
  fi

  git show :1:"$FILE_PATH" > ./tmp.common
  git show :2:"$FILE_PATH" > ./tmp.ours
  git show :3:"$FILE_PATH" > ./tmp.theirs

  git merge-file "$STRATEGY" -p ./tmp.ours ./tmp.common ./tmp.theirs > "$FILE_PATH"
  git add "$FILE_PATH"

  rm ./tmp.common
  rm ./tmp.ours
  rm ./tmp.theirs
}
```

***(Note: I keep updating the script in my GitHub repo, check the repo for the latest improvements: https://github.com/jakub-g/git-resolve-conflict/blob/base/lib/git-resolve-conflict.sh)***

In the particular example as described in the question, the usage would be as follows:

```
git-resolve-conflict --ours package.json
```

For a step by step study see:

https://github.com/jakub-g/git-resolve-conflict

**Bonus:**

If you have multiple `package.json` files in subfolders, and want to resolve the merge [for all of them which are in conflicted state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874862/245966):

```
for ITEM in $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | grep package.json$); do git-resolve-conflict --ours $ITEM; done
```

Comment: Nice script. However, it fails if run from a directory other than the root of the repo. `git -x` only matches exact matches, but the filename is missing leading path.

Comment: @Matt you can add `cd "./"$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)` in the first line to move to the root of the repo, and then `cd -` at the end to return to previous folder. (It won't work though if you run the script from outside the repo, but this is probably a very niche edge case).