# How to resolve conflict automatically

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a file that is a constant conflict.

It contains just two lines

```
versionCode Int
versionName String in the form of "a.b.c"
```

I want to write an automatic something that will resolve this conflict if it ever exists and always takes the higher version code as the resolver.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but it might be worth asking yourself _why_ the file is in constant conflict. Changing the version number on several branches at the same time is somewhat unusual; usually it's only changed on a release branch and not merged back into other branches.

Comment: `always takes the higher version code as the resolver` ... can you clearly define what this means?  What about the case of a tie?

Comment: Is this an android project by any chance? In any case I would generate the variables automatically at build time from git tags and semantic versioning.

Comment: Also see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231059/apply-git-merge-stategy-only-on-one-file

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if there is a tie, there is no conflict